# PHP ws-* specification

Tags: php, .net, wcf, web-services

I am writing php client for .Net web service which uses ws.* specification. In .net server they use wshttpbinding with Transport with message credentials and for message credential security they use username. I am looking for some framework or extension for php to write a client against ws.* specification web service. I know wcf is the one avialble in .Net. But I am looking something similar to that in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Web Service Framework for PHP. Here is the link http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/